# Why does Doctrine 2 create ~Entity.php file?

Tags: command-line-interface, doctrine-orm

When I generate my entities I have a file prefixed with `~` like a backup file or something

Is it a bug or you need to manually remove them?

Comment: re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5219937/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Doctrine 2 create ~Entity.php file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224809/why-does-doctrine-2-create-entity-php-file)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a backup file that is generated by `EntityGenerator` in Doctrine 2.

You just need to set the property `backupExisting` to `false` in `EntityGenerator` class. The file location is `\Doctrine\ORM\Tools\EntityGenerator`.

Comment: This is a dirty, temporary (will be overwritten right after symfony2 vendor update) and not recommended way. There is an argument to prevent backing up, please see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22452003/227980