# Why does Doctrine 2 create ~Entity.php file?

Tags: command-line-interface, doctrine-orm

When I generate my entities I have a file prefixed with `~` like a backup file or something

Is it a bug or you need to manually remove them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Doctrine 2 create ~Entity.php file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219937/why-does-doctrine-2-create-entity-php-file)

Answer (score 11):

From the official documentation in Symfony2 CLI command:

`$> php app/console help doctrine:generate:entities`

> ....
>
> By default, the unmodified version of each entity is backed up and
>   saved  (e.g. Product.php~). To prevent this task from creating the
>   backup file,  pass the --no-backup option:
>
> ```
>  php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Blog/Entity --no-backup
> ```

So to summarize, you may add `--no-backup` option to your command.

Comment: still a tad dirty. any developer worth their salt should version control. Perhaps a git hook to delete those may be worthwhile

Comment: Yes developers (should) use version control however this backup procedure has nothing to do with the version control. Assume you are developing a feature on your local copy and your code is "dirty" (you have been working on the same feature for 3 hours) and you ran `doctrine:generate:entities` command and "something went wrong"! So, yes it is annoying and perhaps as you say; a post-commit hook or preferably `.gitignore` rule will tidy up the code base; however the existence of this feature is understandable.